# emacs python jedi error

Tags: python, emacs, jedi

I am trying to setup my GNU Emacs 24.3.1 for python development following the instructions here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cZ7szFuz18

The installation gave a few warnings but was successful. Then I open a new buffer with file `01.py` and try to use the auto-complete:

```
import os
os.
```

But get this error:

```
deferred error : (error Server may raise an error :   File "/home/avilella/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-0.1.2/jediepcserver.py", line 71
    return _WHITESPACES_RE.sub(' ', desc) if desc and desc != 'None' else ''
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
)
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it's related to this github issue, which apparently was closed by @syohex: github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emacs is using an old version of python. The code that gets the error is python 2.6+ syntax I believe.